# Where on the Internet can I find sound files so that I can hear the alveo-palatal consonants?

Tags: phonetics, transcription

Where on the Internet can I find sound files so that I can hear the alveo-palatal consonants?

I've been relying on this chart ...

https://westonruter.github.io/ipa-chart/keyboard/

... to help me transcribe material in the IPA, but it seems to be missing characters for the alveo-palatal consonants, namely these:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolo-palatal_consonant .

Obviously, the latter site has characters for the alveo-palatal consonants, but I can't seem to find sound files for them on the Internet, not even here:   https://www.yorku.ca/earmstro/ipa/consonants.html

So, where could those sound files be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be what you have in mind, but you could try language-specific sites. For example, if you go to...

http://www.mandarintools.com/worddict.html

and switch the input type to Pinyin, you can search for any syllable in Mandarin using Pinyin input. The results will provide hyperlinks to audio samples of a native speaker pronouncing the syllables. For example, if you type in 'xi', it will take you to the following page:

http://www.mandarintools.com/cgi-bin/wordlook.pl?word=xi&searchtype=pinyin&where=whole&audio=on

Click on any of the hyperlink-ified syllable names, and you will get to hear the voiceless alveo-palatal fricative pronounced by a native Mandarin speaker. The following syllables in Mandarin start with alveo-palatal consonants:

```
[tɕʰ]: qi, qia, qian, qiang, qiao, qie, qin, qing, qiong, qiu, qu, quan, que, qun 
[tɕ]: ji, jia, jian, jiang, jiao, jie, jin, jing, jiong, jiu, ju, juan, jue, jun 
[ɕ]: xi, xia, xian, xiang, xiao, xie, xin, xing, xiong, xiu, xu, xuan, xue, xun
```

A similar site exists for Japanese:

http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1C

Again, be sure to check the box for 'Search using romanized Japanese'. Then type in one of the following syllables:

```
[tɕ]: cha, chi, chu, cho
[dʑ]: ja, ji, ju, jo
[ɕ]: sha, shi, shu, sho
```

The results page will show little play buttons next to the entries; you can click on these play buttons to hear the syllables pronounced by native speakers.

I'm sure there are comparable sites for other relevant languages, but these are the ones with which I'm familiar!

Answer (score 0):

Try the Paul Meier website: http://www.paulmeier.com/consonants/. Hover the mouse over the symbol to see its name, and press for the sound.

Comment: Actually the alveopalatal consonants are not on the main consonant page (which only includes sounds on the "main" IPA chart), but I did some exploring on the site and found the fricatives here: http://www.paulmeier.com/othersymbols/. Unfortunately, since affricates are considered "compositional", there are no examples of alveo-palatal affricates.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Czech] university (Palacký Olomouc) page on the Polish language with a fair amount of examples for [(non-voiced) ɕ](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=5310) and [(voiced) ʑ](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=5311) ; with samples from 3 different speakers and [numerous words](http://polfon.upol.cz/examples.php?sound=5310) in the "more examples" section. It's useful to hear the consonants in both initial and final syllabic position (in my opinion). They have similar pages for the [t͡ɕ](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=5410) and [d͡ʑ](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=5411) affricates. (Basically, the alveo-palatal sibilants.)

Polish does have the retroflex versions for contrast/comparison; both non-palatized [ʂ](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=4300) and [ʐ](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=4301) and (positional) palatized [ʂʲ](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=4310) & [ʐʲ](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=4311), and likewise for the corresponding affricates like [t͡ʂ](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=4400) etc., which you can hear voiced by the same speakers.

Alas Polish doesn't have a broader spectrum of alveolo-palatal consonants found in some Asian languages (stops, nasals, and liquids) that Wikipedia mentions in the page you liked to in your question, but it notes e.g. that

> the Polish nasal represented with the letter ń is a palatalized laminal alveolar nasal and thus often described as alveolo-palatal rather than palatal.

On that university website there is actually a page with a single example for [ɲ̊](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=5110) in "pieśń", where it's described as (voiceless) palatal though. And more numerous examples for the [voiced ɲ](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=5111) as in "dzień".